# how to change eventName with socket.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, socket.io

Use Socket.io I would like to use state to handle the events my socket is listening too. The issue is that once the socket event name is set I can't change it. What I am hoping to do is have socket.io listen to events with eventName start. Then if a button is pressed socket.io will listen to events with different new eventName

```js
state = {
  channel:'start'
};

componentDidMount() {
  // .. lots of other stuff
  apiListener()
}

apiListener = () => {
  mySocket.on(this.state.channel, data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
}

render(){
  return(
    <View>
      <Button onPress={()=> setState({channel: 'great'})} />
      <Button onPress={()=> setState({channel: 'better'})} />
    </View>
  )
}
```